# Django provide API for 3rd Party Usage

Tags: android, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

We are having our own solution in Django and we are using DRF & JWT for generating API for our Android App (so that the APIs created would hit our server and the django code would work on it and thereafter doing necessary CRUD operations).

Now, we are planning to have our APi the option to be consumed by 3rd party users, so that their solution can directly access our API.

We need to know whether the API was hit by our own Android app or javascript code or was it hit by the third party code (we need to have a count on the no. of times the 3rd party has hit our API).
Is there anyway we can solve this?

If we were to provide a separate API for 3rd parties and separate API for our own usage, then using javascript, one can easily read our internal API and abuse them (i.e., hit our server with our internal api from their 3rd party code).

Any generic help to get us started in the right direction, so that we can read and learn through would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into Permissions (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) and Throttling (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/). You may want to block/throttle certain user agents, example curl, android, etc.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class UserAgentBlacklist(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Please set a custom user agent when using scripts with our API.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user_agent = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        for agent in ['libcurl', 'Python-urllib', 'python-requests']:
            if user_agent.startswith(agent):
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: I'm using JWT permission system already. But I would like to know is there any way (there must be) to separate an API call from our android app or from our JS code from calls of 3rd party codes? Regarding throttling, I'm not thinking about the no.of times a user accesses our solution using API. I just need the actual count.

Comment: Updated comment with a sample code to explain how permissions can be used to block certain clients.

Comment: Now, let's say we have an 3rd party app using android and also our own app using android....How would these two be differentiated?  This would help.

Comment: For eg, what I meant was http_user_agent could be same for 2 different android apps, right? (One would be our app another would a different third party app, which is just calling our API). Same for 2 chrome calls (one can be from our website, another can be from a 3rd party website). I wanted a mechanism to differentiate between these two.

Comment: In this case, the differentiation may be done on the client (while not ideal as it can be forged). For example if you're using reactjs you would pass a specific prop to indicate your own app, and then leave the logic on the server.

Comment: That's what I have been planning. But as you said it's not ideal. I'm looking forward to what should ideally be used. Anyone can read by reactjs file and copy it.... that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Still I cannot understand why not using custom permission classes. One for authenticated by your app, and other open for third parties, each of them yielding to a different business logic (list/create/retrieve etc..)

Comment: For authenticating my app using custom permission, at best I'll be sending some additional data from the front end, right (eg: 'sent_from':'my app' would we sent as a header)? In that case, an important part of the authentication lies with the front end. Is not that insecure? Like if someone gets to know that all we do to differentiate APIs is through this additional data, then our internal API can be abused, right?

Comment: No I am suggesting using a specific username/token that only you / your app knows

Comment: Ok. Exactly. Lets say username = "J.Doe" & toekn="randomtoken". Now, our api is: www.domain.com/abcd/dowork (and lets say its post). How do I know that it's being sent from our app or 3rd party? Do you want us to store token for each access and store our app's token and token for 3rd parties separaely?